# How could I return the result of fs.lstat method from function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, fs

I try to check if a given path is a folder or a file. I have to do this async, and to display the result on a pug file, not on the console.

```
const fs = require("fs");
module.exports = function (path) {
fs.lstat(path, (err, stats) => {
    if(err)
        return console.log(err);
    if (stats.isFile())
        return(`Is file: ${stats.isFile()}`);
    if (stats.isDirectory())
        return(`Is directory: ${stats.isDirectory()}`);
});
```

}

Comment: Are you using express? Can you show the code for your route you display the pugfile with?

Comment: Thank you man. You saved me a lot of time! Best explanation ever.

Comment: Hey no problem @CristianBoicu glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 3 ways to render callback to pug layout

There are two ways to return a value from an async function namely, callbacks or promises, 
but honestly if you only use the call once it wouldn't 
be all that different from inlining your call to fs.lstat in your routing, so I'll provide
that as a third option.

### Directory structure for the example

If you want to follow along here is the directory structure for this example.

```sh
.
├── app.js
├── stat.js
└── views
    └── index.pug

1 directory, 3 files
```

### Installing dependencies

You'll want to install express and pug for this example

```
npm install pug express
```

### An example layout

First off here's an example layout `./views/index.pug` we'll use for demonstration purposes:

```
html
    head
        //- This title comes from the express res.render 
        title= title
    body
        //- This title comes from the express res.render 
        h1= title
        //- This message comes from the express res.render 
        p= statResult
```

### Example 1: callbacks

This is a possible directory/file reporting function using callbacks. A callback
is basically what you are already sending into fs.lstat here
where just making a simple change to it's output by wrapping
it in our own node-style callback named `cb`. Node style callbacks
generally have two parameters an error as the first parameter and the data as the second.
We'll follow the node-style callback pattern. Wrapping fs.lstat with our own callback
allows the function calling our function to only
get the returned values we want rather than all of the info
fs.lstat might provide otherwise.

We put this function in a file named `stat.js` for example purposes.
Unless you know what to do with the error inside stat.js
its best to pass the error through the callback in case the 
calling function can handle the error in a better way.
It's important not to swallow/lose errors in Node.

```js
// stat.js
const fs = require("fs");
module.exports = function (path, cb) {
    fs.lstat(path, (err, stats) => {
        if (err)
            return cb(err);
        if (stats.isFile())
            return cb(null, `Is file: ${stats.isFile()}`);
        if (stats.isDirectory())
            return cb(null, `Is directory: ${stats.isDirectory()}`);
    });
}
```

#### Usage of our callback function

Here is how a simple express app would use this callback. We'll
put this in a script file named `app.js` for example purposes.
Notice how we set the 'view engine' to 'pug' and we
`res.render` the 'index.pug' in our views directory.

```js
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const stat = require('./stat.js');
const port = 3020;

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/views', function (req, res) {
    stat("./views", (err, statResult) => {
        if (err) {
            res.render("Oops something went wrong!");
            console.error(err);
        }
        res.render('index', {
            title: "Views Directory Stat Result",
            statResult: statResult
        })
    })
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    stat("./app.js", (err, statResult) => {
        if (err) {
            res.render("Oops something went wrong!");
            console.error(err);
        }
        res.render('index', {
            title: "App.js Stat Result",
            statResult: statResult
        })
    });
})


app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("app listening on http://localhost:" + port)
})
```

### Example 2: promises

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) 
are a really handy tool for async code if you understand
them well enough they can pay off huge improvements to error handling.

Here's your custom stat example code using a promise. Notice how it
returns the newly constructed promise this is important because
promises are values that represent a value that most likely comes
some time in the future. Promises constructors provide you with 
a resolve and reject function. This is because a promise can be in any
one of three states, "pending" meaning it hasn't finalized it's state
or 'resolved' or 'rejected'. Rejecting a promise with an error is kind
of like throwing an error in synchronous code. This is a replacement for our old `stat.js`
file.

```js
// stat.js
const fs = require("fs");
module.exports = function (path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.lstat(path, (err, stats) => {
            if (err)
                return reject(err);
            if (stats.isFile())
                return resolve(`Is file: ${stats.isFile()}`);
            if (stats.isDirectory())
                return resolve(`Is directory: ${stats.isDirectory()}`);
        });
    })
}
```

The following is how you would use that `stat.js` file in a simple app.
One thing to note is that you have to chain `.then`s on a promise to get
the value out of them if they are resolved and if you want to catch any rejected promises
 you need to use `.catch` to catch them. Just like with sync code when you catch an error
it assumes you've handled the error unless you rethrow it.
There are quite a few things to know about promises and I won't cover everything for 
brevities sake, but I'll link some articles at the bottom where you can learn more.

Although the alternative to chaining is to use async/await
which is where you use a function with the keyword `async` before the function
keyword which allows you to use the `await` the Promise value as if it was synchronous.
You can think `await` as unwrapping the value out of the promise. Below is the code for the
new `app.js` in the promise implementation, with route `/views` doing the chaining api
and route `/` doing the async/await api:

```js
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const stat = require('./stat2.js');
const port = 3020;

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/views', function (req, res) {
    stat("./views").then(statResult => {
        res.render('index', {
            title: "Views Directory Stat Result",
            statResult: statResult
        })
    }).catch(function (err) {
        res.render("Oops something went wrong!");
        console.error(err);
    })
})

app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const statResult = await stat("./app.js");
        res.render('index', {
            title: "App.js Stat Result",
            statResult: statResult
        })
    } catch (err) {
        res.render("Oops something went wrong!");
        console.error(err);
    }
})


app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("app listening on http://localhost:" + port)
})
```

### Example 3: Inlining the call to lstat

This is probably not what you want to do if you want to not repeat yourself,
but it's always an option to inline your call to lstat. Thus, you would only
have an `app.js` file and it would look like this:

```js
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 3020;

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/views', function (req, res) {
    fs.lstat("./views", (err, stats) => {
        if (err) {
            res.render("Oops something went wrong!");
            console.error(err);
        }
        let statResult = "";
        if (stats.isFile())
            statResult = `Is file: ${stats.isFile()}`;
        if (stats.isDirectory())
            statResult = `Is directory: ${stats.isDirectory()}`;
        res.render('index', {
            title: "Views Directory Stat Result",
            statResult: statResult
        })
    });
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.lstat("./app.js", (err, stats) => {
        if (err) {
            res.render("Oops something went wrong!");
            console.error(err);
        }
        let statResult = "";
        if (stats.isFile())
            statResult = `Is file: ${stats.isFile()}`;
        if (stats.isDirectory())
            statResult = `Is directory: ${stats.isDirectory()}`;
        res.render('index', {
            title: "App.js Stat Result",
            statResult: statResult
        })
    });
})


app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("app listening on http://localhost:" + port)
})
```

Well that's about the only three ways to return an async value
to be rendered in pug. Hope that helps, feel free to ask me
any questions you have about this code in the comments.
I honestly suggest getting good at promises for things
that only have a single return value when called.

Here's some references for promises:

[MDN's Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

[Jake Archibald's JavaScript Promises: an Introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)